# Add text from TextField by clicking a button into listView using C++

Tags: c++, qml, c++17, qtquick2, qt-quick

I need to add a text from `TextField` by clicking a button in `ListView` (making a chat app on android for my school project).
I'm new in QT and if it's difficult, please write full code for that with descriptions.

**Main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import Chatting 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: "Hello world"
    header: Label{
        id: headerTop
        height: 50

        Text{
            text: "Chat"
            color: "white"
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }

        Button{
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            id: clearChat
            height: 52
            width: 40
            background: Rectangle{
                color: clearChat.down ? "#14181E" : "#1B2129"
                radius: 18
                border.color: "#CECECE"
                border.width: 0.6
            }
        }

        background: Rectangle{
            color: "#131821"
        }
    }

    Chatting{
        id: mainchat
    }

    Rectangle{
        objectName: "myRect"
        id: chatpage
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "#0D1117"

        ListView {
            objectName: "chatlist"

        }


        Row{
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            Rectangle{
                width: 400
                height: 60
                color: "#0D1117"
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                Row{
                    TextField{
                        x: 2.5
                        y: 5
                        id: inputFromUser
                        color: "white"
                        height: 50
                        width: 300
                        background: Rectangle{
                            color: "#1B2129"
                            radius: 14
                            border.color: "#CECECE"
                            border.width: 0.6
                        }
                    }

                    Button{
                        anchors.left: inputFromUser.right; anchors.leftMargin: 5
                        id: getUserValue
                        height: 62
                        width: 50
                        background: Rectangle{
                            color: getUserValue.down ? "#14181E" : "#1B2129"
                            radius: 18
                            border.color: "#CECECE"
                            border.width: 0.6
                        }
                        icon.source: "icons/whitesend.png"
                        icon.width: 50
                        icon.height: 62
                        onClicked: {
                            
                            inputFromUser.text = ""
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QSettings>
#include "chat.h"
#include <chat.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(u"qrc:/mainUI/Main.qml"_qs);
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreationFailed,
        &app, []() { QCoreApplication::exit(-1); },
        Qt::QueuedConnection);

    qmlRegisterType< chat >("Chatting", 1,0, "Chatting");

    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

**chat.cpp**

```
#include <QQuickItem>
#include <QObject>
#include <QStringListModel>
#include "chat.h"

chat::chat(QObject *parent)
    : QObject{parent}
{

}

void chat::chat1()
{

}
```

**chat.h**

```
#ifndef CHAT_H
#define CHAT_H

#include <QObject>


class chat : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit chat(QObject *parent = nullptr);

public slots:
    void chat1();
};

#endif // CHAT_H
```

I'd try to add a custom model but it doesn't work for me

Comment: what does your "_doesn't work_" mean? Btw I see no model in the code. the `ListView` is empty. Please provide [mcve], an example which describes and reproduces the issue.